# Получить данные из json в php

Tags: php, json

Получаю json с длинной > 4000(json 10 твитов). При преобразовании в объект или массив получаю архитектуру с глубокой вложенностью. Нужно достать значения с самых глубин. Решения задачи с кучей вложенных циклов хоть для поиска очень громоздкое. Как правильно нужно работать с json для получения конкретных значений.

Упрощенный пример json:

```
{
    "users": [{
        "id" : 1,
        "name": "Bill Gates",
        "age": 43,
        "somedata": [{
                      "somevalue1": [{
                                       "something1": "value1",
                                       "something2": "value2"
                                    ]}
                      "somevalue2": [{
                                       "something3": "value3",
                                       "something4": "value4"
                                    ]}
                     ]}
        "somedata2": [{
                       "somevalue1" : "justvalue"
                     ]}
    }, {
        "id" : 2,
        "name": "Sergey Brin",
        "age": 33,
        "somedata": [{
                      "somevalue1": [{
                                       "something1": "value1",
                                       "something2": "value2",
                                       "something5": "value5"
                                    ]}
                      "somevalue2": [{
                                       "something3": "value3",
                                       "something4": "value4"
                                    ]}
        ]}
        "somedata2": [{
                       "somevalue1" : "justvalue"
                     ]}
    }, {
        "id" : 3,
        "name": "Larry Page",
        "age": 34,
        "somedata": [{
                      "somevalue1": [{
                                       "something1": "value1"
                                    ]}
                      "somevalue2": [{
                                       "something3": "value3",
                                       "something4": "value4"
                                    ]}
                    ]}
        "somedata2": [{
                       "somevalue1" : "justvalue"
                     ]}
    }]
}
```

Необходимо получить все значения из somevalue1 из вложения somedata для каждого user.  При этом он может быть и пустой, и на разных уровнях вложенности может повторяться somevalue1 как из примера из во вложении somedata2 значения которого не нужны.

Comment: Чем [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php) не угодил?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно, например, преобразовать json  в массив и перебрать значения циклом.

```
$values = [];
$arr = json_decode($json);
foreach($arr['users'] as $user){
    foreach($user as $key => $value){
        if($key == 'somedata'){
            foreach($value as $key2 => $value2){
                if($key2 == 'somevalue1'){
                    $values[] = $value2;
                    // здесь можно прокрутить $value2 еще одним цыклом и так дальше
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

общий принцип понятен, дальше можно доделывать, чтобы все устраивало.

Comment: Вот это в вопросе я и назвал громоздким решением... не ужели это единственный способ?

Comment: Мда, если бы я был повнимательней, то не пришлось бы столько писать))) Но насколько я знаю JSON (англ. JavaScript Object Notation) - тоесть он не предназначен для PHP  и PHP работает с ним только предварительно декодируя. Ну а дальше можно с массивом не только перебором работать, но и комбинировать циклы с поиском array_filter, array_key_exists, array_keys и т.д.